# Exclamation mark before an object?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Coming from java, learning angular/typescript: The `!` negates booleans or boolean expressions. This is, according to my research, the same in javascript/typescript. But what does the following method do?

```
  isSelected(product: Product): boolean {
    if (!product || !this.currentProduct) {
      return false;
    }
    return product.sku === this.currentProduct.sku;
  }
```

What is `!product`? Product is coming in as a method parameter and then it is asked, if product is not product, or wtf should that mean? :D

Comment: It's a way to check for `falsy` values, so if the value of `product` is `falsy`, then do stuff. `falsy` values include: `0, '', false` and some more that I can't remember.

Comment: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#user-content-non-null-assertion-operator

Comment: Wow that's cool. It's basically a "broader" null-check in java while being way more simple. Thanks guys!